# maven-install-plugin: installing submodule jar files

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I have an aggregation project with a half-dozen submodules.  The builds all work but when I try *mvn install:install-file* I only get the top-level pom.  I've also tried *mvn install:install* I get the error "Cannot override read-only parameter: packaging in goal: install:install".

I have the install plugin specified in all submodules.

Parent POM:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <file>pom.xml</file>
    <groupId>com.pillardata</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Child POM:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>     
  <configuration>

    <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar/</file>
    <groupId>com.pillardata</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Other people seem to have this working but I've been hitting a dead-end after several hours of research and trying everything (reasonable) I can think of.

Ideas?

P.S., this is maven 2.2.1.

Comment: I assume what you call parent POM and child POM in your question are only snippet of the actual POM, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand fully your question, so here it is.

You have a project with some modules, like this:

```
   A
   |
   +-- B
   |
   +-- C
```

and you need to 'install' each module's artifact in the maven local repository. Then all you need to do is run:
`mvn install`

you can run this from either (sub-)module and the whole sub-tree will be installed. If you want to install them individually (i.e. prevent the command from being called on each sub-module) then you can use the `-N` flag:
`mvn install -N`

There shouldn't be any need to define anything whatsoever to install artifacts for you maven project.

Comment: Yes, that's the layout of my modules.  One parent that is packaged as a pom and 6 submodules that are packaged as jars.

Comment: When I do _mvn install:install_ I get this error on the first submodule:

    "ERROR: Cannot override read-only parameter: packaging in goal: install:install"

It doesn't matter if I have the plugin stanza in the submodule or not. (I tried using the stanza to specify a new packaging type.)  If I do _mvn install:install-file_ I get the pom installed but none of the submodules.  If I explicitly cd into the submodule tree and run a _mvn install:install-file_ there it succeeds as long as I have the stanza pointing to my jar file and pom file in the submodule's pom.xml file.

Comment: You don't want/need to call `mvn install:install` but simply `mvn install`…

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit the parent pom in the sub-projects and specify the children in the parent as "modules". See [POM][1]

Comment: Yup, I can successfully build and jar everything, it's just the install to the local .m2/repository that's flaking out on me.